# ratio of exponentials, different scales

Tags: probability, integration

$U$ and $V$ are exponentially distributed with scale parameters $\theta_1,\theta_2$. What is the expectation of $U/(U+V)$?

By a conditioning argument, I can reduce the problem to computing the definite integral
$$
\int_0^\infty s^{-1}(e^{-\theta_2 s} - e^{-\theta_1 s}) ds,
$$
so I would be satisfied with that computation as well. But, the problem is described as "a straightforward calculation" in van der Vaart, Asymptotic Statistics, p.56. So it would be nice to know if there is some easier solution than the route I took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral has two problems.  One is the infinite extent at the high end, but that will be controlled by the exponential factors.  The second is that the integrals of each term diverge logarithmically near zero because the exponentials are close to $1$.  The difference of exponentials subtracts off the $1$ and leaves you with an integrable function so the integral is well defined.  I would break the integral into three pieces, $(0,\epsilon), (\epsilon, 1), (1, \infty)$  For the first, we can take the integrand to be the first term of the Taylor series, $\theta_1-\theta_2$.  That eliminates the singularity at $0$ and the integral is $\epsilon(\theta_1-\theta_2)$.  The second is $Ei(-\theta_2)-Ei(-\epsilon \theta_2)+Ei(-\epsilon \theta_1)-Ei(-\theta_1)$ where $Ei$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).  The last comes out in incomplete Gamma functions but I can't get Alpha to answer now (though it did before).

Comment: I find it annoying when Wolfy fails to answer a question when it has previously answered an almost identical question.

Comment: @martycohen:  in this case it had answered it before but I didn't copy the answer and couldn't get it back again.